# Make a <DIV> occupy all VISIBLE height screen, with content below it

Tags: html, css

My client wants a big image showing on the homepage of her site, BUT she wants that ONLY the image be visible when the page loads. All the rest of the page should be below this image and viewable only if the page is scrolled. When the page first loads, the visitor should only see the big image, no matter what monitor size or resolution he/she uses.

Something like this:

```
Screen boundary ->----------------- |
                  IMG               |
                  IMG               |
                  IMG               |
                  IMG               |
                  IMG               |
Screen boundary ->----------------- |
                  Content           |
                  Content           | <- scroll bar
```

Is it even possible?
It's a Wordpress site, if this information matters.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure. You will need to scale the image to $(window).height(); (using jquery) then possibly with a little smartness make the image crop nice...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin:0;
  height: 100%;
}
#foo {
  background-color:#ccc;
  height: 100%;
}

<div id="foo">hello. content goes here</div>
rest of my content<br />
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/isakuy/1)

You can set a background image on the div and play with the various [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) properties to make it look however you want.

Comment: It works like a charm! Would it be possible to make it work with any other content, instead of just with a background image? I mean, can I use a <img> or even a JQuery slideshow?

Comment: For some reason, when I put it into my actual code, it does not work. I think I have some CSS or nested <DIV> conflict.

Comment: Yeah, the DIV can have any content.