# Website that has fixed length but more underneath

Tags: html, dreamweaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a <DIV> occupy all VISIBLE height screen, with content below it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848389/make-a-div-occupy-all-visible-height-screen-with-content-below-it)

This probably has a strange title as I was not sure how to call this, however I am wanting to make a website similar to fiftythree.com where you see the homepage but then if you scroll down the navigation buttons appear.  No matter the screen resolution if you open the website it will always be hidden until you scroll down.  What is this called and how could I go about replicating it, thanks!

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you are describing in the website you've linked. The buttons I see are just a Footer, they are always there.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think it's a totally legitimate question to ask how this technique is called and how it is done.

Comment: Answered a similar (same thing, different application) question the other day (linked above as possible duplicate). it's just 100% height on a div, really.

Comment: I have created a simple example here in case it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/jjMH6/
Like sachleen says, the trick is to use a height of 100%. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a div for your navigation and a div for your main content. 
This website does not have a fixed navigation bar. 
You might want to consider using a fixed position in your css if you want the navigation bar to be fixed. Also you might want a minimum width for your body tag (also css). This avoids your navigation elements stacking up on a small window.